# Data not loading in WebView but it loads after lock - unlock device

Tags: android, android-webview

I have data with some of the html tag, and I want to display it in webView.

I tried below code:

```
String html = "<html><body><font face=\"verdana\" size=\""
                + getResources().getString(R.string.WebView_Font_Size)
                + "\" color=\"rgb(64,64,64)\">"
                + Article.getDetaildescription().replaceAll("h2", "h4")
                + "</font></body></html>";
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
Log.e("htmlstring", html);
description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Issue is: whenever above code executes, nothing loads in webview. But as soon as I lock device & unlocked it, my webview displays that data.

Comment: try if this works: **webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");**

Comment: i did not saved data in any file, same code works in other activity but did not works here

Answer (score 1):

your code seems ok. check your xml file it might helping you .. i wonder if you are dynamically set visibility of any your layout or something ..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html,"text/html","utf-8","about:blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want enable javascript before loading data.

```
String strWeb = "<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-weight: normal; font-size: medium; \"><img src=\"http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/assetmanager/images/gns_header.jpg\" alt=\"\" align=\"middle\" border=\"1px\" height=\"90\" width=\"550\"></span></div><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-family: Verdana; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; \"><br><div style=\"text-align: center;\">Yes we are coming at E & I? Are you?</div></span><br><h1 style=\"font-weight: bold; \"><span style=\"font-family: Verdana; font-size: 14pt; \">News for the day...</span></h1><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; \">Template Mobile Sites for IC: <a href=\"http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/\">http://icmobilesite.vidushiinfotech.net/</a></span><br><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 13px; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">Promotional valid till 30 Sept 2011: MOBILE WEBSITE (Base Product Mobile CMS) for JUST $159<br></span></span><br><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">Mobile Template link: </span><a href=\"http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/\"><span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"font-size: 15px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">http://newsletter.vidushiinfotech.net/Mobilesite/</span><br></a><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; \"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; \"><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">With the promotion on Business Edge and eFusion still running successful in e market place - $ 499</span><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); \">Check out some of the latest site launch on: </span><br><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; \">http://www.randallcontracting.co.uk/Pages/Default.aspx </span><br><br><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-size: 10pt; \"><span style=\"font-weight: bold; \">Category</span>: Building & Construction</span><br></span><br></span><div style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); text-align: left; \"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; \">Description: WELCOME TO RANDALL CONTRACTING Randall Contracting is a family-run contracting SME which has been servicing London and the South East since 1956. Working closely with our Clients and external Design Consultants, we place great emphasis on a safe, positive, practical and common sense approach to our projects. Our delivery methods have resulted in an extensive volume of repeat business from both Private and Public Sectors. Safety and Environmental concerns are a high priority on all our contracts and we continually strive to source innovative working methods and solutions. Our equipment is regularly updated and maintained to ensure minimal environmental impact.</span><br><br></div><span style=\"color: rgb(105, 105, 105); font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma; \"><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; \"><br></span></span><br>";
    WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
    setContentView(webview); 
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webview.loadData(html,"text/html","utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jaimin answer I got hint.

My old layout file contain one linear layout in other linear layout, so I change webview's height to wrap content , also change scroll view's width to fill parent & remove one unnecessary LinearLayout.

old layout with issue

```
<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header_layout" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_background"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/button_share" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Article_Detail_Share"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Quarterly Issue - 10 / 2011"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/s16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"

                android:padding="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image_box_big" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/text_header_red"
                android:textSize="@dimen/s20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/s11sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Web_Description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Image_Gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:spacing="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/bottom_layout" />
```

updated layout file

```
<include
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header_layout" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_background"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/button_share" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Article_Detail_Share"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Quarterly Issue - 10 / 2011"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/s16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" > -->



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"

                android:padding="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image_box_big" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/text_header_red"
                android:textSize="@dimen/s20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Author"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/s11sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        <!-- </LinearLayout> -->

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Web_Description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/Article_Detail_Image_Gallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:spacing="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/bottom_layout" />
```

i know that having webview & gallery inside scroll view is not good approach but its project requirement.